# Convert short URL

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Two day old novice to Python (and programming) so please be gentle.

I have about 1500 shortened URLs scraped from Twitter. They are all in the following format: http://t.co/...

Using this to expand the short URL:

```
import urllib2  
a = urllib2.urlopen('http://t.co/..')  
print a.url
```

The last two lines repeated about 1500 different times with different URLs.

It works well as long as the page to which the URL points to exists however when it doesn't there is an error message and it stops at that point. What do I add to the code so that it returns a "page not found" and continues on to the next URL and goes through the entire list without stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using python 2 (python 3 has slightly other syntax for exception handling)

```
for url in urls:
    try:
        a = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "Error", e
        continue

..... do something with a
```

Comment: Much obliged, will try this as soon as I get back from classes and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Guess I spoke too soon, I am still getting error messages which stop the process from finishing. Any suggestions?                This is what I get, or at least the first few lines of the error message:                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Nanu/Documents/urltest.py", line 969, in <module>
    a = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

Comment: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

Comment: Then you should also handle `urllib2.URLError`.

Comment: I did that and this is what I get now. Thanks for your help.                                                        NameError: name 'a' is not defined